# Remove empty optional properties from object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I´m trying to clean a typed object from empty optional properties with a helper function, and it all works fine. The problem is that i'm running in strict mode and cant figure out how to
solve the strict error i get on the result in the if-statement.

```
export function removeEmptyOptionalProperties<T>(obj: T extends unknown ? any : any): T {
  const result = {} as T;
  Object.keys((obj)).forEach(prop => {
    if (obj[prop] || obj[prop] === false || obj[prop] === 0 || obj[prop] === Array.isArray) {
    /* Here ---> */  result[prop] = obj[prop] as T;
    }
  });
  return { ...result };
}
```

Test example:

```
const testObject = {
      undefinedProp: undefined,
      nullProp: null,
      falseProp: false,
      zeroProp: 0,
      emptyString: '',
      filledString: 'filledString',
      filledObject: {
        filledString: 'filledString',
      },
      filledArray: [
        {
          filledString: 'filledString',
        },
      ],
    };

const result = removeEmptyOptionalProperties(testObject);
console.log('result:', result);
```

The const result shouldn't have any properties that is: undefined, null or ''.
Ive tried to look at the error it generates, but cant figure it out how to solve it.
Error:
'Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'unknown'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'unknown'.ts(7053)
'
https://typescript.tv/errors/#TS7053

As said, this function works, but 'strict' dosen´t like it. So I need a solution so 'strict' likes it. Any ideas?

Comment: why not use `if (obj[prop] != null && obj[prop] !== '')`, that would drop anything that has is  `null`, `undefined` or an empty string (in case you want to remove `''`). The other way around is harder to understand

Comment: In in case this is your code you also probably wanted to do `Array.isArray(obj[prop])` because I don't think your objects contain the `Array.prototype.isArray` function itself. That check isn't necessary though since arrays would already match `obj[prop]` since empty arrays aren't [falsey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues in the above code:

1. `Object.keys(obj).forEach` doesn't take into account, the type of the keys. All the keys will be of type `string`. So, you will have to manually cast them to the type `keyof T`.
2. In this code, `result[prop] = obj[prop] as T`, you are converting `obj[prop]` to type `T` and assigning to `result[prop]` which is incorrect because `result` is of type `T` and `result[prop]` is of type `T[typeof prop]`.

```
export function removeEmptyOptionalProperties<T>(obj: T extends unknown ? any : any): T {
  const result = {} as T;
  Object.keys((obj)).forEach((prop) => {

    const key = prop as keyof T // Address first problem

    if (obj[prop] || obj[prop] === false || obj[prop] === 0 || obj[prop] === Array.isArray) {

        result[key] = obj[prop] as T[typeof key];  // Address second problem

    }
  });
  return { ...result };
}
```

Comment: That looks cleaner then my solution. Thanks @vignesh153 ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it by making the result as a Record, which means that you can add any properties to that object, then returning it as the type that came in.

Like this:

```
function removeEmptyOptionalProperties<T>(obj: T extends unknown ? any : any): T {
  /* const result = {} as T; */
  const forLoopResult: Record<string, unknown> = {};
  Object.keys((obj)).forEach(prop => {
    if (obj[prop] || obj[prop] === false || obj[prop] === 0 || obj[prop] === Array.isArray) {
      forLoopResult[prop] = obj[prop];
    }
  });
  const result: unknown = { ...forLoopResult };
  return result as T;
}
```